metaplex createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction is not a function
This is the error I'm getting:
[0] Error creating token: TypeError: createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction is not a function
[0]     at /home/ubuntu/solana-token-creator/routes/create.js:52:43
[0]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I'm making an app for simply creating tokens on the website, everything works fine except metadata for which I'm using @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata.
My code:

router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Starting token creation process...');
    const { tokenDecimals, tokenInitialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol, tokenURI } = req.body;


    const config = configDb.read('config');
    const walletPrivateKey = config.wallet_private_key;
    const solanaNetwork = config.solana_network;

    const METAPLEX_PROGRAM_ID = new web3.PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s");

    try {
        const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl(solanaNetwork), 'finalized');
        const wallet = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.default.decode(walletPrivateKey));
        const publicKey = wallet.publicKey;

        const MINT_SIZE = splToken.MintLayout.span;
        const TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = new web3.PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA");

        if (!publicKey) {
            throw new Error('Failed to derive public key from wallet.');
        }

        const lamports = await splToken.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);
        const mintKeypair = web3.Keypair.generate();
        const tokenATA = await splToken.getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintKeypair.publicKey, publicKey);
        
        const createMetadataInstruction = createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction(
            {
                metadata: web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
                    [
                        Buffer.from("metadata"),
                        METAPLEX_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
                        mintKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer(),
                    ],
                    METAPLEX_PROGRAM_ID,
                )[0],
                mint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
                mintAuthority: publicKey,
                payer: publicKey,
                updateAuthority: publicKey,
            },
            {
                createMetadataAccountArgsV3: {
                    data: {
                        name: tokenName,
                        symbol: tokenSymbol,
                        uri: tokenURI,
                        creators: null,
                        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
                        uses: null,
                        collection: null,
                    },
                    isMutable: false,
                    collectionDetails: null,
                },
            },
        );
        
        const createNewTokenTransaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
            web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
                fromPubkey: publicKey,
                newAccountPubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey,
                space: MINT_SIZE,
                lamports: lamports,
                programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            }),
            splToken.createInitializeMintInstruction(
              mintKeypair.publicKey, 
              tokenDecimals, 
              publicKey, 
              publicKey, 
              TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),
            splToken.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
              publicKey,
              tokenATA,
              publicKey,
              mintKeypair.publicKey,
            ),
            splToken.createMintToInstruction(
              mintKeypair.publicKey,
              tokenATA,
              publicKey,
              tokenInitialSupply * Math.pow(10, tokenDecimals),
            ),
            createMetadataInstruction
          );
          
          await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, createNewTokenTransaction, [wallet, mintKeypair]);
          console.log('Token created successfully!');




    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating token:', error);
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Failed to create token',
            error: error.message
        });
    }
})

module.exports = router;


That's because createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction isn't a method exported by the @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata library
Metaplex has wrapper functions you can use to initialize the token and metadata accounts without needing to send out different instructions,
For example, when creating a fungible token, you can use the createFungible helper function
import { percentAmount, generateSigner, some } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi'
import { createFungible } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const mint = generateSigner(umi)
await createFungible(umi, {
  mint,
  name: 'My Fungible',
  uri: 'https://example.com/my-fungible.json',
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5),
  decimals: some(7), // for 0 decimals use some(0)
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)

If you need to initialize the SPL token and add metadata in different transactions, you can first create and initialize the SPL token mint using createMint function from mpl-toolbox
    let tx = await createMint(umi, {
        mint,
        decimals: 6,
        mintAuthority: umi.identity.publicKey,
        freezeAuthority: null,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

    let txSig = base58.deserialize(tx.signature);
    console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txSig}?cluster=devnet`);

And finish off with adding the metadata in a separate transaction with the createMetadataAccountV3
    const metadataAccountAddress = await findMetadataPda(umi, {
        mint: mint.publicKey,
    });

    const tx = await createMetadataAccountV3(umi, {
        metadata: metadataAccountAddress,
        mint: mint.publicKey,
        mintAuthority: umi.identity,
        payer: umi.identity,
        updateAuthority: umi.identity,
        data: {
            creators: null,
            name: tokenMetadata.name,
            symbol: tokenMetadata.symbol,
            uri: tokenMetadata.uri,
            sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
            collection: null,
            uses: null,
        },
        collectionDetails: null,
        isMutable: true,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

    let txSig = base58.deserialize(tx.signature);
    console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txSig}?cluster=devnet`);


The error createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction is not a function suggests that the function isn't accessible from the @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata package. This often happens because of either a mismatch in the package version or the function being unavailable in that version. Here are steps you can take to resolve this:

Check Package Version Compatibility

Ensure you have the latest version of @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata installed. You can update it with:
npm install @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@latest


After updating, recheck the official documentation or GitHub repository to confirm that createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction exists in the package version you're using.



2.Verify Imports

Make sure that you’re importing createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction correctly. Typically, it should look something like this:
const { createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction } = require('@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata');


If this import doesn’t work, try importing directly from the package's internals or check if the function is available as createMetadataAccountV2Instruction or similar (sometimes functions have different names in package updates).


Alternative: Use an Older Metadata Instruction

If the version you're using doesn’t support createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction, you can attempt to use createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction or another version if it's available.
For example, with @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata version 0.9.0 and above, createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction is often available.


Confirm @solana/web3.js and @solana/spl-token Versions

Ensure compatibility between @solana/web3.js, @solana/spl-token, and @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata. You may need to update these libraries as well:
npm install @solana/web3.js@latest @solana/spl-token@latest




Test with Minimal Metadata Creation

To verify that metadata creation works, try creating metadata with a minimal setup and see if the transaction is successful. This approach can help isolate if the issue is specifically with createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction.



Applying these steps should help resolve the error or identify an alternative method to create metadata

Why post an AI generated answer?
